# return multiple values from Java script not working on firefox ( Working fine on IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a master js file ( say name : my-dataTables.js ) and accessing it from view (groovy) which is calling functions from my-dataTables.js.

```
proto.dataTable = {
    'filterOptions': function( selectedFilter ) {

        var dCodes = "" ;
        var dCodes2 = "";  

        if ( selectedFilter == 'test1'  ) 
        {
            dCodes = "something 1";
            dCodes2 = "something 2";
        }
        else 
        {
            dCodes = "something 2";
            dCodes2 = "something 1";
        }

        return {
        'dCodes': dCodes,
        'dCodes2': dCodes2
        };  
 }
```

And to access them from view ( groovy):

```
$('#filter-status').change(function () {
    var filterOptions = proto.dataTable.filterOptions($(this).find('option:selected').text());

    var dCodes = filterOptions.dCodes;
    var dCodes2 = filterOptions.dCodes2;

    alert(dCodes + " isRegex : " + dCodes);
});
```

**Working fine on IE, means "proto.dataTable.filterOptions" was called and returned expected value on IE. But on Firefox, it looks like that it reached $('#filter-status').change(function () but not inside proto.dataTable.filterOptions(). And NO error message. Not sure what I am missing. Can any one help?**

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't introduce a newline between the `return` and the `{` at some point?

Comment: "Working fine" is not very well defined...

Comment: Do you see any error messages in Firefox?  What do they say?  Are you using Firebug or any other JS debug tool?

Comment: "Working fine" means "proto.dataTable.filterOptions" was called and returned expected value from IE. But on Firefox It looks like that it reached $('#filter-status').change(function () but not inside proto.dataTable.filterOptions(). And NO error message.

Comment: @Drise- Thanks. I did not know how to accept and why that is important. Now I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The code is fine. It was browser cache issue. I cleaned up the cache and the code worked as expected.**